# Random order of ACF Repeater Field in Timber

Tags: twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm trying to show an Advanced Custom Fields repeater in custom order in a Timber/Twig based WordPress theme. Is it possible to install the array-extension (http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html) to achieve this or how can it be done? I'm completely lost at the moment and would appreciate any ideas on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a twig extension.

Why not something like this:

```
$rows = get_field( 'repeater_field' );
if( $rows ) {
    shuffle( $rows );

    foreach( $rows as $row ) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php file (index.php, page.php etc.)

```
// Create context
$context = Timber::get_context();

// Get Field
$repeat = get_field('my_repeater_field');

// Shuffle it
shuffle($repeat);

// Add it to context
$context['repeat'] = $repeat;
```

And then call it in your twig file as your normally would

Answer (score 0):

Using Timber, you can also do this with the Twig sort filter:
{% for item in items|sort(rand) %}
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html